# Распарсить blob в sql

Tags: sql, oracle

В базе данных есть blob поля. В них храниться информация. Можно ли средствами sql посмотреть что лежит внутри?

Comment: А что в них лежит? Блоб - он слегка не типизированный, в одной записи может лежать "Война и мир" в fb2, в другой - Лунная соната во flac, в третьей - "Hello world" в CP1251...

Comment: @Zufir цифры, скорей всего decimal но думаю тут это не имеет значения. Там просто числовые данные.

Comment: @Zufir возможно, можно как то выгрузить всю эту кучу информации в файл? с помощью sql? Или как то по другому отобразить запросом в чём то повместимее чем varchar2?

Answer (score 2):

Если в блобе лежит просто текст - используйте UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_field)
[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee029/1)

Comment: Кастую вот таким вот способом `select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(THICKLEAD) from PIPE_GEOMETRY
where PIPE = 614478;` и вылетает ошибка `ORA-22835: Размер буфера недостаточен для преобразования CLOB в CHAR или BLOB в RAW (фактически: 5760, максимум: 2000)` Возможно там слишком много информации, идёт переполнение на сколько я понял аж на 3760 больше возможного, как эту инфу можно разбить что бы я её всё таки увидел? Или во что то более вместимое впихнуть.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь пакетом [`UTL_FILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70906).

[Пример от @StevieG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6332633/5741205):

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       NUMBER := 1;
  l_blob      BLOB;
  l_blob_len  NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT blobcol
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   table
  WHERE  rownum = 1;

  l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);

  -- Open the destination file.
  l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(<location>,<filename>,'wb', 32767);

  WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
  END LOOP;

  -- Close the file.
  UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
/
```

PS `<location>` - это имя директории (`directory object`), который создается при помощи `create or replace directory ...`.

Пример:

```
SQL>  create directory MY_BLOBS as '<full_directory_path_on_Oracle_server>';
```

после этого можно использовать это след. образом:

```
l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MY_BLOBS','file.txt','wb', 32767);
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста в каком формате нужно указывать путь и имя файла? указал путь 'D\:' и имя 'file.txt' ругается на то что неверный путь.

Comment: @Андрей, `<location>` - это имя директории (`directory object`), который создается при помощи `create or replace directory ...` и должен находиться на __сервере__

Comment: И что тогда там должно указываться? Просто сам блоб же в базе находиться. Какой я должен указать путь и имя? И кстати я могу запустить этот код просто в worsheet как обычный запрос?